# Strcpy a bigger string to a smaller array of char

Tags: c

Why when I do this:

```
char teststrcpy[5];

strcpy(teststrcpy,"thisisahugestring");
```

I get this message in run time:

```
Abort trap: 6
```

Shouldn't it just overwrite what is in the right of the memory of **teststrcpy**? If not, what does Abort trap means?

I'm using the GCC compiler under MAC OSX

*As a note, and in answer to some comments, I am doing this for playing around C, I'm not going to try to do this in production. Don't you worry folkz! :)*

Thanks

Comment: What IDE/OS are you using/on?

Comment: What do you expect it to do when writing more into a variable than there is room for?

Comment: Abort trap means the OS detected some error and it killed your process. Most likely that "just overwriting" overwrote something it shouldn't have overwritten.

Comment: Many compilers include guard pages explicitly to catch such programming mistakes, in addition to prevent security holes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't own one, but I've read that Mac OS treats overflow differently, it won't allow you to overwrite memory incertian instances. `strcpy()` being one of them

On Linux machine, this code successfully overwrite next stack, but prevented on mac os (Abort trap) due to a [stack canary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries).

You might be able to get around that with the gcc option `-fno-stack-protector`

---

Ok, since you're seeing an abort from `__strcpy_chk` that would mean it's specifically checking strcpy (and probably friends). So in theory you could do the following*:

```
char teststrcpy[5];
gets(teststrcpy);
```

Then enter your really long string and it should behave baddly as you wish.

<sub>*I am only advising `gets` in this specific instance in an attempt to get around the OS's protection mechanisms that are in place. Under NO other instances would I suggest anyone use the code. `gets` is not safe.</sub>

Comment: Building the question’s code into a `main` routine, executing it in the debugger, and showing the resulting stack shows a abort called from `__strcpy_chk`. Using “-fno-stack-protector” does not change this. (Apple clang 4.0, default options, OSX 10.8.2.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Glad to see it was indeed Mac OS... could you try the edit'ed suggestion and see if that does it for you? I suspect the "OS Protection" doesn't apply to the broken/unsafe `gets` function.

Comment: With `gets`, it gets a segmentation fault; it seems to be failing because overwriting the buffer alters important data rather than because it is caught by a checking mechanism. However, a warning is displayed during compilation: “warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Exactly. You were trying to overflow the buffer right? That's what happens when you do, undefined behaviour. In your case a seg fault. There's no promise of how it will react.

Comment: My motivation was not to overflow the buffer, just to provide results for the proposed experiments (which were trying to overflow the buffer). That is, the principal is another person, not me.

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't it just overwrite what is in the right of the memory of `teststrcpy`?

Not necessarily, it's undefined behaviour to write outside the allocated memory. In your case, something detected the out-of-bounds write and aborted the programme.

Answer (score 2):

In C there is nobody who tells you that "buffer is too small" if you insist on copying too many characters to a buffer that is too small you will go into undefined behavior terrority

Answer (score 0):

If you would LIKE to overwrite what's after 5th char of teststrcpy, you are a scary man. You can copy a string of size 4 to your teststrcpy (fifth char SHOLULD be reserved for NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your compiler is using a canary for buffer overflow protection and, thus, raising this exception when there is an overflow, preventing you from writing outside the buffer.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries